# How to compute rowSums in rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm converting an *R* function into Rcpp, where I have used the R function `rowSums`, which appears to not be a valid sugar expression in Rcpp. I found code for an Rcpp version of rowSums [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html). But I'm getting

> error: use of undeclared identifier

when I use `rowSumsC()` in my main Rcpp function.

Is there a easy fix?

Edit: The code

```
cppFunction(
  "NumericMatrix Expcpp(NumericVector x, NumericMatrix w,
   NumericVector mu, NumericVector var, NumericVector prob, int k) {
   for (int i=1; i<k; ++i){
   w(_,i) = prob[i] * dnorm(x,mu[i], sqrt(var[i]));
   }
   w = w / rowSums(w)
   return w;
}")
```

Comment: Please create a reproducible example (e.g. post code and the call). Also, there is an Rcpp sugar equivalent to `rowSums`. It was added in Rcpp 0.12.8

Comment: I've uploaded the code. I can't really call it since it can not be defined due rowSums not being identified. What is the name of the rcpp equivalent to rowSums and do I have to do anything extra to call it? I'm really new to rcpp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Rcpp officially added `rowSum` support in 0.12.8](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/5a99a862c132b21f0c728919cc9a227f4c528d18/inst/NEWS.Rd#L78). Therefore, there is no need to use `rowSumsC` function devised by Hadley in Advanced R.

Having said this, there are a few issues with the code.

---

Rcpp presently does *not* support `Matrix` to `Vector` or `Matrix` to `Matrix` computations. (Support for the later may be added per [#583](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/583), though if needed one should consider using [`RcppArmadillo`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppArmadillo) or [`RcppEigen`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppEigen)). Therefore, the following line is problematic:

```
w = w / rowSums(w)
```

To address this, first compute the `rowSums` and then standardize the matrix using a traditional `for` loop. **Note:** Looping in C++ is very fast unlike *R*.

```
NumericVector summed_by_row = rowSums(w);

for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
  w(_,i) = w(_,i) / summed_by_row[i];
}
```

---

Next, C++ indices begin at `0` not `1`. Therefore, the following for loop is problematic:

```
for (int i=1; i<k; ++i)
```

The fix:

```
for (int i=0; i<k; ++i)
```

---

Lastly, the parameters of the function can be reduced as some of the values are not relevant or are overridden.

The function declaration goes from:

```
NumericMatrix Expcpp(NumericVector x, NumericMatrix w,
   NumericVector mu, NumericVector var, NumericVector prob, int k)
```

To:

```
NumericMatrix Expcpp(NumericVector x, NumericVector mu, NumericVector var, NumericVector prob) {

  int n = x.size();
  int k = mu.size();
  NumericMatrix w = no_init(n,k); 

  .....
```

---

Putting all of the above feedback together, we get the desired function.

```
Rcpp::cppFunction(
  'NumericMatrix Expcpp(NumericVector x, NumericVector mu, NumericVector var, NumericVector prob) {

  int n = x.size();
  int k = mu.size();

  NumericMatrix w = no_init(n,k); 

  for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) { // C++ indices start at 0
     w(_,i) = prob[i] * dnorm(x, mu[i], sqrt(var[i]));
  }

  Rcpp::Rcout << "Before: " << std::endl << w << std::endl;

  NumericVector summed_by_row = rowSums(w);

  Rcpp::Rcout << "rowSum: " << summed_by_row << std::endl;

  // normalize by column to mimic R
  for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
    w(_,i) = w(_,i) / summed_by_row[i];
  }

  Rcpp::Rcout << "After: " << std::endl << w << std::endl;

  return w;
  }')

set.seed(51231)
# Test values
n <- 2
x <- seq_len(n)
mu <- x
var <- x
prob <- runif(n)

mat <- Expcpp(x, mu, var, prob)
```

**Output**

```
Before: 
0.0470993 0.125384
0.0285671 0.160996

rowSum: 0.172483 0.189563
After: 
0.273066 0.661436
0.165623 0.849300
```